# Testing difference between group of values

Tags: statistical-significance, group-differences

I have `n` series of values as follow. Let's say they are scores of students in a class (just example)

```
s1: x1, x2 ... xk

s2: x1, x2 ... xk

..

sn: x1, x2 ... xk
```

I want to test the difference between these series, i.e. to answer the question that: are performances of different student similar or not.

What kind of test I can use?

Thanks a lot,

**Update**

The purpose is, I want to see if students are quite different, they should be divided in different class rather than stay in a same class.

Comment: I think you should edit the title and the tags to reflect the question better.

Answer (score 0):

If all students for example are tested on the same metric, then you should be able to do a t-test/anova to compare two classes (data is assumed to be normally distributed) . As n grows however you will run into the problem of multiple comparisons. Is there any known bound on n?

Comment: Also, the only null being tested is "the average performance is similar across groups". If you have any more specific criteria that you are testing, it would probably have a much more stricter choice of technique.

Comment: Hi, I thought about t-test or KS-test but as you said, it will run to the problem  of n*(n-1)/2 comparisons. Right now, n ~ 5 only, but I have 30 classes.

Comment: @TiếuThủy, what are characteristics of classes? How to distinguish a strong class from a weak class? Above/below a median/mean score? May be use the Kruskal-Wallis test to decide whether the population medians on a dependent variable (scores of students) are the same across all levels of a factor (studends, $s_1, s_2,...., s_n$).

Comment: Hi @Nick, in fact there is no standard. Let's say, if all students have score of 5/10 in all subjects (extreme case), means that they are equal and we do not need to divide the class into two. If half of them always get 0 and half always get 10/10, means that this class is extremely unequal and it should be better to divide students into two classes.